# Error[e46]: Undefined external and Error[Pe020]: identifier "CurrentDataMode" is undefined

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

Hi Everyone i am doing some embedded MSP430 programming and having some problems with my c code. Here below is abbreviated code.

I am receiving the following error:

```
Error[Pe020]:identifier “CurrentDataMode” is undefined etc…
```

When i comment out this line `CurrentDataMode = SYSTEMDataConfig.DataMode;`

I get the following error:

```
Error[e46]: Undefined external “SYSTEMDataConfig” referred in other_thing (file link)
Error while running Linker
```

Some help on this would be truly appreciated.

```
/////////////////////
//thing.c
/////////////////////

#define DATA_OWNER 1
#include “MSP_INC.H”

void init_DATA(void){
    CurrentDataMode = SYSTEMDataConfig.DataMode;
}

/////////////////////
//thing.h
/////////////////////

typedef struct{
    u_char DataMode;
} SYSTEMDATACONFIG;

#if(DATA_OWNER == 1)

const SYSTEMDATACONFIG SystemDataConfig = {
    0
};

u_char CurrentDataMode;

#else

void volatile init_DATA(void);

extern const volatile SYSTEMDATACONFIG SYSTEMDataConfig;

#endif

/////////////////////
//other_thing.c
/////////////////////

#include “..\MSP_INC.H”

static void big_function(void){
    u_char i = SYSTEMDataConfig.DataMode
}
```

Comment: You use two different spellings of SystemDataConfig (the other being SYSTEMDataConfig). Also, the types differs, one is "const" the other "const volatile". If you are new to C, try to rewrite the code without using the "data owner" pattern, even though it will save you some characters in the source code, it is harder to write and understand.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentDataMode is declaread later in the code, after its first use. Put it to the beginning of the code and it will be visible to the function init_DATA.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Fekete, when i add `u_char CurrentDataMode;` to the top of the `other_thing.h` file i get a Error[e27]: Entry "CurrentDataMode" in module ... (file) redefined in module ... (file)
Error while running linker

Comment: Have you declared CurrentDataMode in MSP_INC.H also? If yes, then it will be declared twice, once in this file and once in the .h file.

Comment: I removed `u_char CurrentDataMode;` from `thing.h` to `thing.c` and it clears that error, but produces a new one. Error[e46]: Undefined external "SYSTEMDataConfig" referred i thing (file) Error while running linker

Comment: That's probably because you defined SYSTEMDataConfig later in the file than it is first used.

Comment: TRy this:
Write your code in this order:
1. include files
2. function forward declaration
3. global variables
4. main function
5. function definitions
In this case all your functions will "see" your global variables, and all function will know all other functions.

Comment: Not sure how to do that in relation to the above code. Thanks Fekete for your help so far.

Comment: Ok, then one more comment: put the define from the c file to the h file, as the h file checks the value of the define but it does not know its value.
(So put #define DATA_OWNER 1 to thing.h as this file will check the value of DATA_OWNER)